# jquery fullcalendar not showing time json data

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is the generated json data from PHP code, but I am not able to see the time ex. For a meeting event time, I am very new to this, if someone can give me solution would be a great help.

```
[{"title":"All Day Event","start":"2013-09-01T00:00:00+04:00","allDay":"true"},{"title":"Long Event","start":"2013-09-09T00:00:00+04:00","end":"2013-09-12T00:00:00+04:00","allDay":"true"},{"id":"999","title":"Repeating Event","start":"2013-09-11T16:00:00+04:00","allDay":"false"},{"id":"999","title":"Repeating Event","start":"2013-09-18T16:00:00+04:00","allDay":"false"},{"title":"Meeting","start":"2013-09-14T10:30:00+04:00","allDay":"false"},{"title":"Lunch","start":"2013-09-14T12:00:00+04:00","end":"2013-09-14T14:00:00+04:00","allDay":"false"},{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2013-09-15T19:00:00+04:00","end":"2013-09-15T22:30:00+04:00","allDay":"false"},{"title":"Click for Google","start":"2013-09-29T00:00:00+04:00","url":"http:\/\/google.com\/","allDay":"false"}]
```

Comment: When you say that you are "not able to see", what do you mean specifically? How are you trying to use the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are wrapping the `allDay` option as string it must be boolean.

Ref: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

From docs:

> Don't include quotes around your true/false. This value is not a
>   string!

Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/HbbfK/

Comment: Your ``jsfiddle`` demo also work with events, where ``allDay`` wrapped as string.

Comment: Completed the fix; with wrap not work, try using the day view; use my fiddle and it's right if you use the OP JSON will not set time of the events